# Calculate the range of double

Tags: c, floating-point

As part of a exercise from "The C programming Language" i am trying to find a way to calculate the maximum possible float and the maximum possible double on my computer. The technique shown below works with `float`s (to calculate the max float) but not with `double`:

```
// max float:
float f = 1.0;
float last_f;
float step = 9.0;
while(1) {
    last_f = f;
    f *= (1.0 + step);
    while (f == INFINITY) {
        step /= 2.0;
        f  = last_f * (1.0 + step);
    }
    if (! (f > last_f) )
        break;
}
printf("calculated float max : %e\n", last_f);
printf("limits.h float max   : %e\n", FLT_MAX);
printf("diff                 : %e\n", FLT_MAX - last_f);
printf("The expected value?  : %s\n\n", (FLT_MAX == last_f)? "yes":"no");

// max double:
double d = 1.0;
double last_d;
double step_d = 9.0;
while(1) {
    last_d = d;
    d *= (1.0 + step_d);
    while (d == INFINITY) {
        step_d /= 2.0;
        d  = last_d * (1.0 + step_d);
    }
    if (! (d > last_d) )
        break;
}
printf("calculated double max: %e\n", last_d);
printf("limits.h double max  : %e\n", DBL_MAX);
printf("diff                 : %e\n", DBL_MAX - last_d);
printf("The expected value?  : %s\n\n", (DBL_MAX == last_d)? "yes":"no");
```

and this results to:

```
calculated float max : 3.402823e+38
limits.h float max   : 3.402823e+38
diff                 : 0.000000e+00
The expected value?  : yes

calculated double max: 1.797693e+308
limits.h double max  : 1.797693e+308
diff                 : 1.995840e+292
The expected value?  : no
```

It looks to me like it still calculates using single precision in the second case.

What am i missing?

Comment: I think it works with float since some of the comparisons are made in double precision. With the double case they are not precise enough.

Comment: Tip: Use `"%a"` to see all the details of `last_d/DBL_MAX`.

Comment: @Bathsheba - yes, i suppose the same, just right now out of ideas how to fix this :)

Comment: Please report your platform's `printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);` as that affects the answer.  It is 2,1,0, -1, etc?

Comment: I'll bet my job on it being down to this - answer below.

Comment: You seem to assume that If `d<DBL_MAX`, then for some *representable* `epsilon>0` `d*(1+epsilon) == DBL_MAX`. This is of course not true.

Comment: @chux this reports '0'

Comment: @Vladimir So your `float` calculation are done with `float` and mine (2 is reported), is done with `long double`. and converges with the hoped for results.  Hmmm'

Comment: @Vladimir Please also report `printf("%d\n", FLT_ROUNDS);` (The rounding mode for floating-point).

Comment: @chux this one shows '1'

Comment: The last `step_d` would be interesting to know.  Is it 3.122502e-17?

Comment: The issue I see is with `d  = last_d * (1.0 + step_d);` vs. maybe `d  = last_d  + step_d*last_d;` as the first can make a `double` intermediate sum of `1.0 + step_d` that is `1.0`, even without `step_d != 0` whereas the 2nd form can use FP math that is a _bit_ wider.  Do you get expected results using `d  = last_d  + step_d*last_d;`?

Comment: @chus Repect! This did the trick - please make an answer from it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's approach works when calculations are done with wider precision than `float` in the first case and wider than `double` in the 2nd case.

In the first case, OP reports `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0` so `float` calculations are done as `float` and `double` are done as `double`.  Note that `float step ... 1.0 + step` is a `double` calculation.

---

The below code *forces* the calculation to *double* and so I can replicate OP's problem even with my `FLT_EVEL_METHOD==2`  (Use `long double` for internal calculations.)

```
  volatile double d = 1.0;
  volatile double last_d;
  volatile double step_d = 9.0;
  while(1) {
      last_d = d;
      d *= (1.0 + step_d);
      while (d == INFINITY) {
          step_d /= 2.0;
          volatile double sum = 1.0 + step_d;
          d  = last_d * sum;
          //d  = last_d  + step_d*last_d;
      }
      if (! (d > last_d) ) {
        break;
      }
  }

diff                 : 1.995840e+292
The expected value?  : no
```

Instead OP should use the following which does not form the **inexact** sum of `1.0 + step_d`  when `step_d` is small, rather it forms the **exact** product of `step_d*last_d`.  The 2nd form results in a more accurate calculation for the new `d`, by providing an additional *bit* of calculation precision in `d`.  Higher precision FP is not needed to employ OP's approach.

```
          d  = last_d  + step_d*last_d;

diff                 : 0x0p+0 0.000000e+00
The expected value?  : yes
```

Comment: Why are your local variables marked `volatile`? Is *that* what forces the calculation to use `double`?

Comment: @Groo Yes, partially.  If my `double` variables are not `volatile`, then with `FLT_EVEL_METHOD==2`, various FP math may occur are wider precision.  So try to force the calculations to only occur at `double` and break `last_f * (1.0 + step)` into 2 steps, insuring the `1.0 + step` sum is not retained internally at higher precision.  Then code is re-formed using `d  = last_d  + step_d*last_d;`  (or even `volatile double product = step_d*last_d; d  = last_d  + product;`) to exercise an alternate method that is more numerically accurate.

Comment: Cool stuff, I never thought I would see it being used in such context. :)

Comment: @Vladimir Some details: The core issue here is that when using FP near its limits of precision/range, it is important to form _exact_ or nearly so  results as able.  With _binary_ FP, `step_d = 1.0; ... step_d /= 2.0;` is always exact (except for 1 case, `DBL_TRUE_MIN/2`).  The compares are _exact_.  `d  = f(last_d, step_d);` is not always going to be exact, yet, letting intermediate values to be _exact_ allows and inexactness (and its rounding) to be part of the last calculation rather than [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) makes for the best result.

Comment: Great answer and great explanation. I wish i could upvote you twice.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions with the literals n.0 are all double precision floating point types. That allows the assignment to f to be calculated using a higher precision intermediate value.

It's this effect that allows the algorithm to converge in the float case.

With strict double precision floating point such convergence is not possible.

If you had used the f suffix on the literals in the float case then convergence would not occur there either.

A fix would be to use long double suffixes on the literals if your platform has a wider long double type.

Comment: Neither 'f' suffix in the float case, not 'L' in the double case changed anything in the output - float is still correct, and the double calculation - still incorrect. Also tried `long double` instead of `double` for the variables with no success.